# Does the processing time differ depending on the SQL query order?

Tags: sql, database

Find the names of all instructors who have a higher salary than some instructor in ‘Comp. Sci’.

1. ```
   select distinct T.name
   from instructor as T, instructor as S
   where T.salary > S.salary and S.dept_name = ‘Comp. Sci.’
   ```
2. ```
   select distinct T.name
   from instructor as T, instructor as S
   where S.dept_name = ‘Comp. Sci.’ and T.salary > S.salary
   ```

is that right 2 query faster than 1 query?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.  And no, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: possibly due to the bit which does the table join coming later, I don't know for sure but it sounds plausible, because it might do the test of the dept_name on more records (unnecessarily). I could be wrong. But either way it's better and clearer to use proper JOIN syntax anyway.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how do you know which product OP is using?

Comment: @Mike It probably doesn't matter, since internally both the explicit and implicit joins would likely have the same execution plan.  I think, at least.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen some products don't support JOIN syntax

Comment: @Mike But all the major relational databases certainly do.  The OP should tag with the database though, you are right about that.

Comment: Er, you just completely changed the queries we've all been commenting on. Not helpful. What are you actually having trouble with? Is this a theoretical question, or is your actual test-verified experience that one is significantly slower? Have you checked the query plans for each? Are they the same, or not? What about the queries you originally posted? It's not good to entirely change the question after people have started looking at it! And please tag your DBMS

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @ADyson sorry... 
I did not know there was an answer soon. I did not know if there was a comment and asked a question. Regardless of the DBMS, I'm curious.

Comment: If you're that curious, you can easily test it yourself. The real speed is likely to depend on more factors than just the pure code, anyway. But in general, the order of items in the where clause is not significant. You can verify it by looking at the query plans

Comment: I am curious. Whether or not the cartesian product occurs according to where statement.

Comment: @ADyson thank you! I will try to be a query plan once.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a decent SQL database system with a reasonable optimizer, they should produce the exact same result using the same (or equivalent) execution plans.

SQL tries, as much as possible, to be a *declarative* language. You tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*.

As such, the *order* of evaluation of individual predicates is not usually defined by any particular product. (Some exceptions may exist).

If there were two different tables here, any decent optimizer should be trying to apply the `dept_name` based predicate *as* it scans/seeks within the `S` table (perhaps choosing to use an index that allows it to answer that predicate cheaply) and before it supplies any rows to the join predicate, no matter what order those predicates are supplied in the `WHERE` clause.

As it is here though, due to the inequality in the join predicate, the best we can probably hope for is a single scan of the `instructor` table. If there's an index on `salary` it may be able to use that to cheaply assess the inequality (otherwise it may choose to perform a sort on the data if it's smart enough and the stats warrant it).

---

So, to sum up, keep things simple. Write simple, straightforward queries that are easy to understand the *intent* of. Then, *measure* the performance and, if it's not adequate, start investigating execution plans to determine where the costs/potential missing indexes are and work from there.

Do *not* try to learn "golden rules" that say you must always do X or Y to get the "best" performance.